# PHP if item is empty in XML

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to remove a node if the child attritbutes are empty.

XML is a http request with simpleXML, which i cannot paste here.
Therefor im pasting some of the XML document from the url:

**THE XML**

```
<game id="1421692" status="Pre-Game" summary="1:00 PM" PreRegPost="Regular Season" PreRegPostID="2" GameDate="11/2/2014 1:00:00 PM">
<HomeTeam HomeTeam="Vikings" HomeTeamAbr="Min" HomeTeamID="16" HomeScore="0" Home_Outcome="undecided">HomeTeam</HomeTeam>
<AwayTeam AwayTeam="Redskins" AwayTeamAbr="Was" AwayTeamID="28" AwayScore="0" Away_Outcome="undecided">AwayTeam</AwayTeam>
game
</game>
<game id="" status="" summary="" PreRegPost="" PreRegPostID="2" GameDate="">
<HomeTeam HomeTeam="" HomeTeamAbr="" HomeTeamID="16" HomeScore="" Home_Outcome="">HomeTeam</HomeTeam>
<AwayTeam AwayTeam="" AwayTeamAbr="" AwayTeamID="" AwayScore="" Away_Outcome="">AwayTeam</AwayTeam>
game
</game>
<game id="1421668" status="Pre-Game" summary="1:00 PM" PreRegPost="Regular Season" PreRegPostID="2" GameDate="11/16/2014 1:00:00 PM">
<HomeTeam HomeTeam="Bears" HomeTeamAbr="Chi" HomeTeamID="3" HomeScore="0" Home_Outcome="undecided">HomeTeam</HomeTeam>
<AwayTeam AwayTeam="Vikings" AwayTeamAbr="Min" AwayTeamID="16" AwayScore="0" Away_Outcome="undecided">AwayTeam</AwayTeam>
game
</game>
```

**THE PHP**

```
  foreach ($game->{'info-schedule'}[0]->game as $games) {
    //Get the Date and Time for the game
    $time = $games->attributes()->GameDate;
    //Get the HomeTeam Data
    $hometeam = $games->HomeTeam->attributes()->HomeTeamAbr;
    $hometeamscore = $games->HomeTeam->attributes()->HomeTeamScore;
    //Get the AwayTeam Data
    $awayteam = $games->AwayTeam->attributes()->AwayTeamAbr;
    $awayteamscore = $games->AwayTeam->attributes()->AwayTeamScore;
    //Change TimeZone
    $playtime = new DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
    $playtime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Copenhagen'));


        $playtimes .= "<li class='time'>".$playtime->format('d/m - H:i')."</li>";
        $versus .= "<li class='versus'>".$hometeam."<span class='HomeTeamScore'>".$hometeamscore."</span><span class            ='AwayTeamScore'>".$awayteamscore."</span>".$awayteam."</li>";


  }
```

**THE HTML**

```
<div class="results">
<ul>
<?php echo $playtimes; ?>
</ul>
<ul>
<?php echo $versus; ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

My output current looks like this:

```
02/11 - 22:00 / MinWas
16/06 - 00:37 /         //This is supposed to come out all empty
16/11 - 22:00 / ChiMin
```

The problem is that, in the empty node it automatically output my local time even tho its empty.

How do i convert or remove that empty node?

PS. This is my second foreach loop - So don't judge it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a simple validation check to determine whether to process your foreach iteration. From what I understand, you can check that `$hometeam` is not empty (unset, blank, empty, zero, false, etc) before adding the results. This will skip the iteration completely if it is blank using [`continue()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/control-structures.continue.php):

```
foreach ($game->{'info-schedule'}[0]->game as $games) {
    if(empty($hometeam))
        continue;

    // rest of your code
}
```

Something you should keep in mind is that large concatenations like that are fine but are a little messy, and you should consider using an array like this:

```
$play_time = array();
$versus = array();

foreach ($game->{'info-schedule'}[0]->game as $games) {
    if(empty($hometeam))
        continue;

    // rest of your code
    $play_time[] = "<li class='time'>".$playtime->format('d/m - H:i')."</li>";
    $versus[] = "<li class='versus'>".$hometeam."<span class='HomeTeamScore'>".$hometeamscore."</span><span class='AwayTeamScore'>".$awayteamscore."</span>".$awayteam."</li>";

}
```

Then you output like this (using [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)) (note: you could use a `\n` or `PHP_EOL` separator to have your output a little cleaner in the source code):

```
<div class="results">
    <ul>
        <?php echo implode($play_time); ?>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <?php echo implode($versus) ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And another side note too, blocks of HTML like that might be easier expressed using an [`sprintf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) call to insert formatted content into a string:

```
$pt_format = '<li class="time">%s</li>';
$vs_format = '<li class="versus">%s<span class="HomeTeamScore">%s</span><span class="AwayTeamScore">$s</span>$s</li>';

foreach ($game->{'info-schedule'}[0]->game as $games) {
    if(empty($hometeam))
        continue;

    // rest of your code
    $play_time[] = sprintf($pt_format, $playtime->format('d/m - H:i'));
    $versus[] = sprintf($vs_format, $hometeam, $hometeamscore, $awayteamscore, $awayteam);
}
```

Just a thought :) It's a bit easier to read like that.

Answer (score 0):

Skip an iteration with the `continue` keyword if the awayteam does not exist.

```
foreach ($game->{'info-schedule'}[0]->game as $games) {
    //Get the Date and Time for the game
    $time = $games->attributes()->GameDate;
    //Get the HomeTeam Data
    $hometeam = $games->HomeTeam->attributes()->HomeTeamAbr;
    $hometeamscore = $games->HomeTeam->attributes()->HomeTeamScore;

    if (empty($games->AwayTeam->attributes()->AwayTeamAbr)) {
        continue;
    }

    //Get the AwayTeam Data
    $awayteam = $games->AwayTeam->attributes()->AwayTeamAbr;

    $awayteamscore = $games->AwayTeam->attributes()->AwayTeamScore;
    //Change TimeZone
    $playtime = new DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
    $playtime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Copenhagen'));


    $playtimes .= "<li class='time'>".$playtime->format('d/m - H:i')."</li>";
    $versus .= "<li class='versus'>".$hometeam."<span class='HomeTeamScore'>".$hometeamscore."</span><span class            ='AwayTeamScore'>".$awayteamscore."</span>".$awayteam."</li>";
}
```

Comment: That doesn't remove the entire line i pointed out, which shows my local computer time in middle line.

Comment: The problem using using `isset()` to check this is that the variable **is** set, it's just a blank string. You need to check that it's not blank as well.